# CSS DIV column-count height not adjusted

Tags: html, css, webkit, multiple-columns, blink

I'm trying to achieve a 3 column layout using the `column-count` property. But it gives me strange effects in **Webkit** and **Blink** (Google Chrome) *[Firefox 3.6+ works fine]*. If you look at the attached code and run the snippet, you can see that there is some extra space after the checkboxes and before the button at the end.
[image: image of the problem, rendered in Safari]
Actually, as you can see in the inspector, the `<div class="centeredForm formEntry optionList">` containing the `<div class="centeredForm optionListMainContainer" style="margin-top: -1.525em;">` gets the wrong height. It behaves as the `column-count`property was not set.
Is there a workaround for this problem in Webkit?

```css
/*! normalize.css v3.0.2 | MIT License | git.io/normalize */

/**
 * 1. Set default font family to sans-serif.
 * 2. Prevent iOS text size adjust after orientation change, without disabling
 *    user zoom.
 */

html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  /* 1 */
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  /* 2 */
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  /* 2 */
}
/**
 * Remove default margin.
 */

body {
  margin: 0;
}
/* HTML5 display definitions
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Correct `block` display not defined for any HTML5 element in IE 8/9.
 * Correct `block` display not defined for `details` or `summary` in IE 10/11
 * and Firefox.
 * Correct `block` display not defined for `main` in IE 11.
 */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
main,
menu,
nav,
section,
summary {
  display: block;
}
/* Forms
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Known limitation: by default, Chrome and Safari on OS X allow very limited
 * styling of `select`, unless a `border` property is set.
 */

/**
 * 1. Correct color not being inherited.
 *    Known issue: affects color of disabled elements.
 * 2. Correct font properties not being inherited.
 * 3. Address margins set differently in Firefox 4+, Safari, and Chrome.
 */

button,
input,
optgroup,
select,
textarea {
  color: inherit;
  /* 1 */
  font: inherit;
  /* 2 */
  margin: 0;
  /* 3 */
}
/**
 * Address `overflow` set to `hidden` in IE 8/9/10/11.
 */

button {
  overflow: visible;
}
/**
 * Address inconsistent `text-transform` inheritance for `button` and `select`.
 * All other form control elements do not inherit `text-transform` values.
 * Correct `button` style inheritance in Firefox, IE 8/9/10/11, and Opera.
 * Correct `select` style inheritance in Firefox.
 */

button,
select {
  text-transform: none;
}
/**
 * 1. Avoid the WebKit bug in Android 4.0.* where (2) destroys native `audio`
 *    and `video` controls.
 * 2. Correct inability to style clickable `input` types in iOS.
 * 3. Improve usability and consistency of cursor style between image-type
 *    `input` and others.
 */

button,
html input[type="button"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  /* 2 */
  cursor: pointer;
  /* 3 */
}
/**
 * Re-set default cursor for disabled elements.
 */

button[disabled],
html input[disabled] {
  cursor: default;
}
/**
 * Remove inner padding and border in Firefox 4+.
 */

button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/**
 * Address Firefox 4+ setting `line-height` on `input` using `!important` in
 * the UA stylesheet.
 */

input {
  line-height: normal;
}
/**
 * It's recommended that you don't attempt to style these elements.
 * Firefox's implementation doesn't respect box-sizing, padding, or width.
 *
 * 1. Address box sizing set to `content-box` in IE 8/9/10.
 * 2. Remove excess padding in IE 8/9/10.
 */

input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* 1 */
  padding: 0;
  /* 2 */
}
/**
 * Define consistent border, margin, and padding.
 */

fieldset {
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  margin: 0 2px;
  padding: 0.35em 0.625em 0.75em;
}
/**
 * 1. Correct `color` not being inherited in IE 8/9/10/11.
 * 2. Remove padding so people aren't caught out if they zero out fieldsets.
 */

legend {
  border: 0;
  /* 1 */
  padding: 0;
  /* 2 */
}
div.subVCs {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.view-size-100p {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 2px 6px 3px 6px;
}
@media only handheld,
only screen and (max-width: 1024px),
only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
  .view-size-100p {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
}
html,
html * {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html p,
html a,
html ul,
html ol,
html li {
  font-size: 16px;
}
body {
  margin: 5px;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
form.centeredForm {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
form.centeredForm > fieldset {
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #d3d3d3;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 10px;
}
form.centeredForm > fieldset > legend {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.centeredForm .formEntry {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
}
.centeredForm .formEntry.submit,
.centeredForm .formEntry.button {
  text-align: right;
}
.centeredForm .formEntry.hidden {
  display: none;
  width: auto;
}
.centeredForm .formEntry.spacer {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: block;
}
.centeredForm .formEntry > label,
.centeredForm .formEntry > input,
.centeredForm .formEntry > div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.125em 0.375em 0.1875em 0.375em;
}
.centeredForm .formEntry > label {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 40%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
.centeredForm .formEntry:not(.hidden) > input,
.centeredForm .formEntry.optionList > div,
.centeredForm .formEntry.select > div,
.centeredForm .formEntry.radio > div {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  width: 60%;
}
.centeredForm .formEntry.submit > input,
.centeredForm .formEntry.button > input {
  width: 30%;
}
.centeredForm .formEntry:not(.submit):not(.button):not(.hidden) {
  text-align: right;
}
.centeredForm .formEntry.optionList .optionListMainContainer {
  -webkit-column-width: auto;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 0;
  -webkit-column-rule: none;
  -moz-column-width: auto;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-gap: 0;
  -moz-column-rule: none;
  column-width: auto;
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 0;
  column-rule: none;
}
.centeredForm .formEntry.optionList .optionListMainContainer,
.centeredForm .formEntry.optionList .optionListMainContainer * {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0.125em 0.375em 0.1875em 0.375em;
}
.centeredForm .formEntry.optionList .optionListMainContainer .optionListTitleContainer {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0.625em;
  margin-bottom: 0.1875em;
  -webkit-column-span: all;
  -moz-column-span: all;
  column-span: all;
  z-index: 0;
}
.centeredForm .formEntry.optionList .optionListMainContainer .optionListTitleContainer:first-child {
  margin-top: -1.525em;
}
.centeredForm .formEntry.optionList .optionListMainContainer .optionListContainer {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px !important;
}
.centeredForm .formEntry.select .selectMainContainer {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0px !important;
}
.centeredForm .formEntry.radio .radioMainContainer {
  -webkit-column-width: auto;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 0;
  -webkit-column-rule: none;
  -moz-column-width: auto;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-gap: 0;
  -moz-column-rule: none;
  column-width: auto;
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 0;
  column-rule: none;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0px !important;
}
.centeredForm .formEntry.radio .radioMainContainer .radioContainer {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px !important;
}
.centeredForm div.formEntry:nth-of-type(2n) {
  color: black;
  background-color: #f5f5ff;
}
/*
 * @CSS3 Inputs
 * @author kellers
 **/

:root input {
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0.5em;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 0.5em;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0.5em;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0.5em;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0.5em;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0.5em;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0.5em;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0.5em;
  border-top-left-radius: 0.5em;
  border-top-right-radius: 0.5em;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0.5em;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0.5em;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #cccccc;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  outline: 0px none;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  padding: 0.125em 0.375em 0.1875em 0.375em;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
:root input:not([type="checkbox"]):not([type="radio"]):not([type="file"]):not([type="hidden"]):not([type="reset"]):not([type="submit"]):not([type="button"]).ui-spinner-input {
  margin: 0px 17px 0px 0px;
}
:root input[type="color"] {
  padding-top: 0px !important;
  padding-bottom: 0px !important;
}
:root span.ui-spinner.ui-widget {
  font-size: inherit !important;
}
:root input[type=number] {
  text-align: right;
}
:root input[disabled] {
  color: #545454 !important;
  -moz-opacity: .4;
  -webkit-opacity: .4;
  opacity: .4;
}
:root input:not([type="checkbox"]):not([type="radio"]):not([type="file"]):not([type="hidden"]):not([type="reset"]) {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
  -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
  transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
}
:root input:not([type="checkbox"]):not([type="radio"]):not([type="file"]):not([type="hidden"]):not([type="reset"]):not([disabled]):focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
}
:root div[data-type="button"] {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
  -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
  transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
}
:root div[data-type="button"]:not([data-disabled]):focus,
:root div[data-type="button"]:not([data-disabled]):hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
}
:root button:not([data-disabled]):not(.ui-datepicker-close):not(.ui-datepicker-current):not(.ui-button) {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
  -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
  transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
}
:root button:not([data-disabled]):not(.ui-datepicker-close):not(.ui-datepicker-current):not(.ui-button):not([data-disabled]):focus,
:root button:not([data-disabled]):not(.ui-datepicker-close):not(.ui-datepicker-current):not(.ui-button):not([data-disabled]):hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
}
:root input[type="button"]:not([disabled]):hover,
:root input[type="submit"]:not([disabled]):hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6) !important;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6) !important;
}
:root input[type="submit"],
input[type="button"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  color: black;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}
:root input[type="submit"]:active,
input[type="button"]:active {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: inset;
  border-color: #808080;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
:root div[data-type="button"],
:root input[type="button"] {
  margin: -1px -1px -1px -3px;
}
:root div[data-type="button"],
:root input[type="button"],
:root div[data-type="button"]:root button:not(.ui-datepicker-close):not(.ui-datepicker-current):not(.ui-button),
:root input[type="button"]:root button:not(.ui-datepicker-close):not(.ui-datepicker-current):not(.ui-button) {
  min-width: 5px;
  line-height: 1;
  display: inline-block;
}
:root button:not(.ui-datepicker-close):not(.ui-datepicker-current):not(.ui-button) {
  margin: -1px -1px -1px 1px;
}
/**
 * @info Cross-browser CSS3 Image-Free Custom Checkbox
 * @author Dmitriy Kubyshkin
 * @changed by kellers
 * @web http://kubyshkin.ru/posts/cross-browser-css3-image-free-custom-checkbox.html
 */

.my_own_styled_checkbox {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
}
.my_own_styled_checkbox * {
  font-size: inherit !important;
}
.my_own_styled_checkbox .checkBox,
.my_own_styled_checkbox .checkBoxOverlay {
  padding: 0px !important;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
.my_own_styled_checkbox .checkBox {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0.125em;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #cccccc;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: white;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 50%;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
  -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
  transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
}
.my_own_styled_checkbox > input {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.my_own_styled_checkbox > input[disabled] {
  cursor: default;
}
.my_own_styled_checkbox > input[disabled] + .checkBox {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #eeeeee;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.my_own_styled_checkbox > input[disabled] + .checkBox > .checkBoxOverlay {
  border-bottom: 0.125em solid #999;
  border-left: 0.125em solid #999;
}
.my_own_styled_checkbox > input[disabled] + .checkBox + span.checkBoxText {
  color: #999;
}
.my_own_styled_checkbox .checkBox > .checkBoxOverlay {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  border-bottom: 0.15em solid black;
  border-left: 0.15em solid black;
}
.my_own_styled_checkbox input:checked + .checkBox > .checkBoxOverlay {
  left: 0.125em;
  top: 0em;
  width: 1em;
  height: 0.375em;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  zoom: 1;
  display: block;
  z-index: 2;
}
.my_own_styled_checkbox input {
  position: absolute;
  outline: none;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  opacity: 0;
}
.my_own_styled_checkbox > input:not([disabled]):active + .checkBox,
.my_own_styled_checkbox > input:focus + .checkBox {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
}
.my_own_styled_checkbox > input:focus + .checkBox,
.my_own_styled_checkbox > input:not([disabled]):hover + .checkBox {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
}
.my_own_styled_checkbox > span.checkBoxText {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-left: 1.5em !important;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="userEdit view-size-100p">
  <div class="userEdit">
    <div class="mainDiv">

      <form class="centeredForm centeredForm" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <fieldset>
          <legend>some title</legend>
          <div class="centeredForm formEntry optionList">
            <label>some label text</label>
            <span style="display: inline-block;width: 60%;margin:0px;padding:0px;visibility: hidden;">&nbsp;</span>
            <div class="centeredForm optionListMainContainer" style="margin-top: -1.525em;">
              <span class="centeredForm optionListContainer my_own_styled_checkbox">
     <input type="checkbox" name="ckeckboxname[]" value="5" checked="checked" tabindex="21"><span class="centeredForm checkBox"><span class="centeredForm checkBoxOverlay"></span></span>
              <span class="centeredForm checkBoxText">Test User</span>
              </span>
              <span class="centeredForm optionListContainer my_own_styled_checkbox">
     <input type="checkbox" name="ckeckboxname[]" value="5" tabindex="22"><span class="centeredForm checkBox"><span class="centeredForm checkBoxOverlay"></span></span>
              <span class="centeredForm checkBoxText">Test User</span>
              </span>
              <span class="centeredForm optionListContainer my_own_styled_checkbox">
     <input type="checkbox" name="ckeckboxname[]" value="5" checked="checked" tabindex="23"><span class="centeredForm checkBox"><span class="centeredForm checkBoxOverlay"></span></span>
              <span class="centeredForm checkBoxText">Test User</span>
              </span>
              <span class="centeredForm optionListContainer my_own_styled_checkbox">
     <input type="checkbox" name="ckeckboxname[]" value="5" tabindex="24"><span class="centeredForm checkBox"><span class="centeredForm checkBoxOverlay"></span></span>
              <span class="centeredForm checkBoxText">Test User</span>
              </span>
              <span class="centeredForm optionListContainer my_own_styled_checkbox">
     <input type="checkbox" name="ckeckboxname[]" value="5" checked="checked" tabindex="25"><span class="centeredForm checkBox"><span class="centeredForm checkBoxOverlay"></span></span>
              <span class="centeredForm checkBoxText">Test User</span>
              </span>
              <span class="centeredForm optionListContainer my_own_styled_checkbox">
     <input type="checkbox" name="ckeckboxname[]" value="5" tabindex="26"><span class="centeredForm checkBox"><span class="centeredForm checkBoxOverlay"></span></span>
              <span class="centeredForm checkBoxText">Test User</span>
              </span>
              <span class="centeredForm optionListContainer my_own_styled_checkbox">
     <input type="checkbox" name="ckeckboxname[]" value="5" checked="checked" tabindex="27"><span class="centeredForm checkBox"><span class="centeredForm checkBoxOverlay"></span></span>
              <span class="centeredForm checkBoxText">Test User</span>
              </span>
              <span class="centeredForm optionListContainer my_own_styled_checkbox">
     <input type="checkbox" name="ckeckboxname[]" value="5" tabindex="28"><span class="centeredForm checkBox"><span class="centeredForm checkBoxOverlay"></span></span>
              <span class="centeredForm checkBoxText">Test User</span>
              </span>
              <span class="centeredForm optionListContainer my_own_styled_checkbox">
     <input type="checkbox" name="ckeckboxname[]" value="5" checked="checked" tabindex="29"><span class="centeredForm checkBox"><span class="centeredForm checkBoxOverlay"></span></span>
              <span class="centeredForm checkBoxText">Test User</span>
              </span>
              <span class="centeredForm optionListContainer my_own_styled_checkbox">
     <input type="checkbox" name="ckeckboxname[]" value="5" tabindex="30"><span class="centeredForm checkBox"><span class="centeredForm checkBoxOverlay"></span></span>
              <span class="centeredForm checkBoxText">Test User</span>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <span class="centeredForm formEntry submit">
   <input type="submit" name="pEditSingleUserGroup" value="some action" tabindex="32">
  </span>
        </fieldset>
      </form>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be more helpful if you reduced your code to just the **relevant** CSS rather than the whole stylesheet.

Comment: it's because you have made your column holder inline-block

Comment: here is update demo link :https://jsfiddle.net/4mepm5dL/

Comment: Looks like Chrome bug [#297782](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=297782) although @RazaHussain has a solution but no explanation on what was changed.

Comment: @Paulie_D I've allready stripped away all code, that does not directly interact, but it's not easy to reduce any further... Therefore i made a live snippet you can go through with a web inspector :-)

Comment: @Pete Using `display: block` on the `div.optionListMainContainer` would break the whole layout, but fix the gap... maybe I'll add some `position: relative;` to bring the layout back... Thx for the tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made few changes in your code here is demo: https://jsfiddle.net/4mepm5dL/

---

**Changes:**

HTML Line 11:
`<div class="centeredForm optionListMainContainer" style="margin-top: -1.525em; float:right"> // added 'float:right'`

HTML Line 55:
`<div style='clear:both'></div> // added`

CSS Line 247:

```
.centeredForm .formEntry > label,
.centeredForm .formEntry > input,
.centeredForm .formEntry > div {
    /*display: inline-block; //removed this line */
    padding: 0.125em 0.375em 0.1875em 0.375em;
}
```

Comment: I flaged your answer as the accepted one, with a bit more tricking i got it fine, but the hint to use `float: right` and afterwards a `div` with `clear: both` fixes the problem. Thx!                                                                                         Also thanks to @Pete and you ( @raza-hussain ) for the hint to not use `display: inline-block;`.

Comment: @pate thanks for updating my answer I ll try to add explanation with my answers in future.